# Linkedin Passport Oauth failureRedirect

Tags: node.js, oauth

Good afternoon,

I'm working in a node application. Concretely I'm working   with  "passport-linkedin-oauth2".

There is my code.

linkedin/index.js

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var auth = require('../auth.service');

var router = express.Router();

router
.get('/', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
state: 'comienzo'
  }),
function(req, res){
// The request will be redirected to Linkedin for authentication, so         this
// function will not be called.
  })

.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
failureFlash : true,
failureRedirect: '/login'

}), auth.setTokenCookie);

module.exports = router;
```

linkedin/passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LinkedInStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;
var models = require('../../api');

exports.setup = function (User, config) {
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
  clientID: config.linkedin.clientID,
  clientSecret: config.linkedin.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: config.linkedin.callbackURL,
  scope:        [ 'r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'],
  state: true
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    // To keep the example simple, the user's LinkedIn profile is returned to
    // represent the logged-in user. In a typical application, you would want
    // to associate the LinkedIn account with a user record in your database,
    // and return that user instead.
    return done(null, profile);
  });

  models.User.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      linkedin: profile.id
    },
    defaults: {
      name: profile.displayName,
      linkedin: profile.id,
      mail: profile.emails[0].value,
      password: 'xxxxxxx',
      role: 'admin', provider: 'linkedin',
      activo: true
    }
  }).spread(function (user, created) {
    console.log("x: " +user.values);
    return done(null, user)
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error occured', err);
    return done(err);
  });

}
));
};
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm pretty sure that LinkedIn is logging properly.

In my app when i press login button it redirect me to LinkedIn webpage, I fill the information and then my server receives  this answer

```
GET /auth/linkedin/callback?code=AQTfvipehBLAXsvmTIl1j3ISYCzF03F-EilhiLlfSJNqiwfQsyHeslLONOWY12Br-0dfV1pgkSSpCKlmtpiMVUCufJlatEBswWqfPe6iahoRF8IHIhw&state=comienzo 302 4ms - 68b
```

I think that this means that it is ok because I get the state that I have sent to LinkedIn API before and the code.

Anyway, every time I login always redirect me to Login page which is     failureRedirect: '/login' ( I have tested that if I change this route, the  app redirect me where this attribute point)

Also I have checked that it never executes the code that search in the db for the linkedin user.

Comment: Debuggind the code I have seen that the value of  flash on req.session is "Unable to verify authorization request state" I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the state property on the handler or at the strategy instantiation, i'm not sure why but this solves the issue.

```
exports.setup = function (User, config) {
  passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    clientID: config.linkedin.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.linkedin.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.linkedin.callbackURL,
    scope:  [ 'r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'],
    state: true // <-- Remove state from here
  })
}
```

and this code

```
router
.get('/', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
  state: 'comienzo' // <-- Or Remove state from here
}),
```

You can just set it the state on one of this places but not both, so remove one of them